# Invalid Binary from the App Store Test Flight MAUI APP

Tags: app-store, maui, testflight

I have recently upgraded from XF to MAUI. I could upload the Android internal version. However, while doing the iOS, I receive an "Invalid Binary" and the app is directly deleted from Test Flight in App Store before doing anything.

I can't find a log in the store to find out what is really causing the error. Looked into info.plist and Entitlments.plist, but can't get my head around what could be wrong with the publish?

Comment: Going through the release mode in iOS, I found that the app crashes because of AutoMapper. This is insane that Automapper is not working in the iOS release.

Comment: Solved the AutoMapper issue. The app runs fine in both debug & release modes on physical devices. However, the App store does the same while submitting to the Test flight. Don't know if MAUI is ready for App Store?

Comment: Please refer to the below link for what causes the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75750921/plugin-firebase-causes-invalid-binary-in-a-maui-release-build-in-app-store