# Plugin.Firebase causes Invalid Binary in a MAUI release build in App Store

Tags: firebase, maui, .net-maui.shell

I am facing an `Invalid Binary` issue with the release build in the App Store. I have an empty sample MAUI app with the following packages.

If I remove the [Plugin.Firebase](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase) package from the project, the app uploads and passes the `TestFlight`. However, when I add the Plugin.Firebase. The app is rejected from the App Store with an `Invalid Binary`. It actually doesn't pass the `TestFlight` and is removed automatically.

This is an empty MAUI app. The app is working perfectly fine with Android, so in the sample, I target iOS only.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
        <!--<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>-->
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MauiTestApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MauiTestApp</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.azee.mauitestapp</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>5570cff5-4abb-454f-971e-7106748a6a4d</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0.9</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>9</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
      <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
      <CodesignProvision>Maui Test App</CodesignProvision>
      <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
      <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="1.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Mopups" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.MediaManager" Version="1.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.MediaManager.Forms" Version="1.2.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <BundleResource Include="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/arahmancsd/MauiTestApp) without the GoogleService-Info-plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to the issue.

[Invalid Binary on App Store iOS release build #148](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/issues/148)